# Is there a simple way to fake prepopulated suggestions onclick, but onchange show autocomplete resuts using material-ui autocomplete?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

Id like to show a popper with data in it which represents a history of searched suggestions on click, but replace that with the default autocomplete dropdown on type, and keep it unless the input is blank. One idea I thought would work was using a onChange handler to detect the length of input typed... which Ive not managed.

On click of the highlighted value Id like to redirect to another page. Currently I'm using json object to hold a few strings, with urls like this.

[image: Edit white-browser-en5wh]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired results, we will be maintaining two seperate options `searchHistory options` & the `default options`. We can toggle between the options by checking if the input field is empty or user has entered something to search through the default options.

I've modified your code on sandbox. Following is the link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-northcutt-fnc03?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That's a good idea, but when you type the `searchHistory` field is not updated with results, instead it defaults to the "No options" results.

Comment: Basically after you type anything it start searching through the `top100Films options`, try entering `the`, all the options (from the `top100Films`) will appear in the dropdown.

Comment: And upon typing anything in the `input field` if you want to search through both the `options` you can simply change the `line:13` to

`options={inputValue ? [ ...top100Films, ...historySearch ] : historySearch}`

Comment: There might be something wrong. I dont get the results you do. Ill refresh and try again

Comment: Nope that does not happen. Typing anything just filtters `searchHistory` not the new options ie `top100Films`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-northcutt-fnc03?file=/src/App.js
Try now ^
line 13: options={inputValue ? top100Films : historySearch}

Comment: My apologies, I should read better. You did mention line 13. Would clicking a option redirect to the url or is that not really possible ?

Comment: No problem :) Yeah that's possible too.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-northcutt-fnc03?file=/src/App.js
now, the url will be opened on clicking the option from dropdown.

Comment: Im busy learning, but wow do I have far to go..  I thank you, Ill be learning from your code sample.

Comment: I did! Not sure why's it's not working. Ill try again later

Comment: ah -> "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."  - awe